# Obtener elementos específicos de un array

Tags: c, array, optimización

Buenas, si yo por ejemplo hago:

```
char buf[1024];
fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);
```

¿Puedo coger los caracteres que escribí del array sin coger los elementos que no utilicé? ¿O tengo que coger los 1024 si o si?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Te refieres a tomar solamente el input que haya ingresado el usuario? o ¿a qué le llamas "coger los caracteres que escribí del array"?

Comment: Si, tomar solamente el input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este caso, la función fgets almacena los caracteres que se ingresen por teclado en tu vector llamado buf.

El número 1024 indica el máximo posible de caracteres a leer, esto quiere decir que si el usuario ingresa 1023 caracteres, se cortará la ejecución de fgets y ya no será posible introducir mas caracteres.

Pero si por el contrario, el usuario solo ingresa 20 caracteres y presiona ENTER. La función fgets dejará de ejecutarse inmediatamente y solo se habrán almacenado en buf 20 caracteres.
Estos caracteres estarán almacenados en la posición 0 a 19 de tu buf y podrás accederlos como quieras.

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar memcpy creando un nuevo char con la longitud de los caracteres que necesitas

```
char nuevo[5];
memcpy(nuevo, &buff[10], 4);
nuevo[4] = '\0'; // Final del string (null byte)
```

Donde 4 es la longitud de caracteres que necesitas mas un byte para poner el byte nulo.